Avoid "jumping" behavior on sticky sidebar
I'm using Tailwind and setting up a left panel with a right hand sidepanel. The left hand panel is dynamic and can have content added to it that expands it vertically. The right hand sidepanel is longer than the height of a screen, and should be sticky so that it never fully leaves the screen.
It's set up like this:
<div class="h-full sm:grid sm:grid-cols-4">
  <div class="col-span-3 bg-white flex flex-col border-t border-t-gray-300">
    dynamically sized content
  </div>

  <div class="col-span-1 sm:border-l sm:border-t sm:border-gray-300 bg-slate-100">
    <div class="sm:sticky sm:top-[58px]">
      <div class="px-4 py-2 border-b bg-white border-b-gray-300 border-t sm:border-t-0 border-t-gray-300">
        don't want content to jump when the left column expands
      </div>
    </div>      
  </div>
</div>

The problem I'd love to solve is that when I'm scrolled to the bottom of the page, where both the right and left column are showing the end of their content, adding any content to the left hand of the page causes the right hand to "jump" because there is now room for it to be stuck to the top as the sticky requires it.
What can I do to avoid jumpy this behavior? It is jarring when it happens live.
